# Using cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs WebClient with TLS produces Certificate Unknown Error

Tags: java, cxf, tls1.2

If I am using the below maven dependency, in combination with TLS, then I am getting an **Certificate Unknown Error**.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

If I am using the below maven dependency, then everthing works as expected.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Even more worse, if I am adding the below dependency, then I am getting the same Error again:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure, what the problem is, but maybe some cxf-spring-boot auto-configuration does produce the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I could verify the problem.

The difference is that the cxf.xml configuration gets not used in any case.

After explicitly importing the cxf.xml into my spring configuration, the problem was solved.